Why am I not getting any option on a li in nextjs
I am trying to make a dropdown menu with available treatments, but when I open the drop down menu I dont see any options despite that I can see the console log of availableTreatments:
interface TreatmentOptions {
  id: number
  name: string
  price: number
  duration: number
}

  const [availableTreatments, setAvailableTreatments] = useState<TreatmentOptions[]>([])


  const fetchTreatments = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:1234/api/treatments", {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })
  
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Failed to fetch available times")
      }
  
      const treatments: TreatmentOptions[] = await response.json()
      setAvailableTreatments(treatments)
      console.log(treatments)
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching available times:", error)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTreatments()
  }, [])

{/* Treatment Options */}
            <div className="relative">
              <label htmlFor="treatment" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-1">
                Treatment
              </label>
              <div className="relative">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="relative w-full bg-white border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-lg shadow-sm pl-3 pr-10 py-3 text-left cursor-default focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 sm:text-sm"
                  aria-haspopup="listbox"
                  aria-expanded="true"
                  aria-labelledby="listbox-label"
                  onClick={() => setIsDropdownOpen(!isDropdownOpen)}
                >
                  <span className="flex items-center">
                    <span className="ml-3 block truncate">
                      {selectedTreatment ? selectedTreatment.name : "Select a treatment"}
                    </span>
                  </span>
                  <span className="ml-3 absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 pointer-events-none">
                    <ChevronDown className="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" />
                  </span>
                </button>

                {isDropdownOpen && (
                  <ul className="absolute z-10 mt-1 w-full bg-white shadow-lg max-h-80 rounded-md py-1 text-base ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 overflow-auto focus:outline-none sm:text-sm custom-scrollbar" tabIndex={-1} role="listbox" aria-labelledby="listbox-label" aria-activedescendant="listbox-option-3">
                    {availableTreatments.map((option, key_id) => (
                      <li
                        key={key_id}
                        className="text-gray-900 cursor-pointer select-none relative py-2 pl-3 pr-9 hover:bg-blue-100"
                        id={`${option.id}`}
                        role="option"
                        onClick={() => {
                          setSelectedTreatment(option)
                          setIsDropdownOpen(false)
                        }}
                      >
                        <div className="flex items-center">
                          <span className="font-normal ml-3 block truncate">
                            {option.name}
                          </span>
                        </div>
                        <span className="text-blue-600 absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-4">
                          ${option.price} ({option.duration} min)
                        </span>
                        {selectedTreatment && selectedTreatment.name === option.name && (
                          <span className="text-blue-600 absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-4">
                            <Check className="h-5 w-5" aria-hidden="true" />
                          </span>
                        )}
                      </li>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                )}
              </div>
            </div>

            {selectedTreatment && selectedTreatment.name === "other" && (
              <div>
                <label htmlFor="specificReason" className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 mb-1">
                  Please Specify the Reason
                </label>
                <textarea
                  name="specificReason"
                  id="specificReason"
                  rows={4}
                  value={specificReason}
                  onChange={(e) => setSpecificReason(e.target.value)}
                  className="pl-4 pr-4 py-3 block w-full border-2 border-gray-300 rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500"
                  placeholder="Provide a detailed description..."
                  required
                />
              </div>
            )}


Be aware that all code the above except the interface is inside a component
Run, dont get any error but dont get the expected result

can you confirm if isDropdownOpen is true
